# jQuery .load() bootstrap modal and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to `.load()` a bootstrap modal in my page and show it immediately. Below is the code I have written (which isn't working as the modal opens but can then never be closed)!

Basically I am trying to `.load()` a list of players in a modal when you click on a team name (with the class `.team`), I've tried various ways of calling `$($this).empty()` with no success.

Here is my function:

```
   $(function () {
        $('.team').on('click', function () {
            var target = $(this).data('target');

            $('#results-modals').load('/team-players.html ' + target, function (response, status, xhr) {
                if (status === "success") {
                    $(target).modal({ show: true });
                }
            });
        });
  });
```

Here is the html anchor and example modal:

```
<a class='team' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#20'>Real Madrid</a>
```

Data held in external file team-players.html:

```
<div id='20' class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <p>Player 1: Ronaldo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That returns a 'Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined'

Comment: Rename your variable to anything else!,  that doesn't start with $.

Comment: And use $(this).attr('data-target') instead of data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `$($this).modal({ show: true });` try `$(this).modal('show');`

To hide the modal, you can use `$(this).modal('hide');`

Answer (score 8):

```js
$(function(){
  var url = "url of the modal window content";
  $('.my-modal-cont').load(url,function(result){
  $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal Window Container -->
<div class="my-modal-base">
 <div class="my-modal-cont"></div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Window content -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
   <h3>Modal header</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <p>My modal content here…</p>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `$(this).modal("toggle")` if it open it will close and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery** .load() bootstrap modal and show

for show   `$(#ID).modal('show');`

for hide `$(#ID).modal('hide');`